# Нет уведомлений о баллах репы в тулбаре

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, репутация, уведомления

Перестали приходить уведомления о новых баллах в тулбаре. Либо у меня только так :)

Comment: Совсем не приходили или с задержкой?

Comment: Минусов по репе не было?

Comment: Или откатов репы.